# Error When Trying To Use PhotoCamera Class CaptureImage Method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have trouble with the `photocamera` class in C# for Windows Phone 8.1. And so far I have gotten it to display in my APP, but have not been so successful on actually saving it. It keeps giving me errors like:

> Show Details  Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
>       Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Stream'  $Project Name   Page2.xaml.cs   42

It Would mean a lot if you could help me, I have been at this for like 3 hours now.

```
if (query.IsPressed)
{
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.SetSource(cam.CaptureImage);
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you add the rest of the related code?

Comment: CaptureImage is a method, and returns void. You can't set a method as the stream which is why you get the error.

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202956(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @Hosney Just goes to show how much I can progress In a year thx to people on stackoverflow like you.